# Error with double backslash in Windows path in Python

Tags: python, file, backslash

I want to work with paths in Windows in Python 3.3, but I have an error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>     'E:\\dir\\.project'

The problem is the double backslash. I read the solution using r.

```
def f(dir_from):
    list_of_directory = os.listdir(dir_from)
    for element in list_of_directory:
        if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(dir_from, element)):
            open(os.path.join(dir_from, element))

f(r'E:\\dir')
```

I have this error again

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>     'E:\\dir\\.project'

`os.path.normpath(path)` doesn't solve my problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Double slahes aren't valid in Windows paths. (Except at the start to indicate an SMB connection to a remote server or to access the unmanaged file system api)

Comment: try changing '\\' for '/'

Comment: Also note that by prefixing the string with `r`, you don't need to escape backslashes. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2081708/156755) for more information

Comment: You are mixing your work-arounds. Either use a raw string (`r'E:\dir'`) **or** double your backslashes, but not both.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are using a [raw-string](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals), then you do not escape backslashes:

```
f(r'E:\dir')
```

---

Of course, this problem (and many others like it) can be solved by simply using forwardslashes in paths:

```
f('E:/dir')
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not know that we can give forward slash in windows file path

Answer (score 0):

Changing '\\' for '/' worked for me. I created a directory named 'a' in C:/ for this example.

```
>>> (Python interpreter)
>>> import os
>>> os.path.isdir('C:/a/)')
>>> True
>>> os.path.isfile('C:/a/)')
>>> False
```

Comment: a agree, this cod is worked for me too, but then i want work with join, i see error