# I can not read file from specified directory

Tags: python, opencv

I tried to read the file from directory but i m unable to read. every time i get the same error. hello.txt is the file name and it contains the content as well. I want to read the file first and then its content line by line.

```
import cv2
f = open("C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hello.txt", "r")
print(f.readline())
f.close()
```

.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-b53fed7bb3dd>", line 3, in <module>
    f = open("C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hello.txt", "r")

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hello.txt'
```

Comment: it seems you don't have this file or folder.

Comment: I have this file. it is present on the desktop (location specified)

Comment: then get path from code and use it in any text editor to check if you can open it. Maybe on desktop you have only shortcut to file which exists in different folder.

Comment: your desktop folder is in OneDrive???

Comment: Is there any problem with the syntax ?

Comment: Yes one drive attached

Comment: syntax is OK but Windows can use files with extension .shortcut to display link to file which is in different folder and other programs may not respect this shortcut.

Comment: you can start with `print(list(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop")))` to check what files Python can see.

Comment: Even though i have changed the location of file. but still im getting the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error with double backslash in Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567785/error-with-double-backslash-in-windows-path-in-python)

Comment: print(list(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop")))
through this python reads all the files including hello.text. 
but when i specify the file it donot read

Comment: do you have `hello.txt` or `hello.text` ? You use two different names.

Comment: it can be other situation - you may have space in filename - ie. at the end - which you can't see on screen but it makes diffference for Python.

Comment: the file name is hello.txt

Comment: you can rename file and try to open with new name.

Comment: i did it too :(((( but it showing me another error: [WinError 267] The directory name is invalid: 'C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hi.txt'

Comment: you can also use `listdir()` and display names with `print(">{}<".format(name))` to see if there is no space.

Comment: did you use new name with `open()` or `listdir()` ?

Comment: from the same location images can be read but not the files. i m not getting whats wrong with it. :(((((

Comment: yes i use new name as well

Comment: do i have to save the text file with "hi" or "hi.txt" , in order to read that file ? may be i m getting error because of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out with this code -

```
with open(r"C:\\Users\\Kazmi-PC\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\hello.txt", "r") as file:
    <some code>
```

This will tell that it is raw string.

**More Information**

[What exactly do "u" and "r" string flags do, and what are raw string literals?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081640/what-exactly-do-u-and-r-string-flags-do-and-what-are-raw-string-literals)

*EDIT:*

Python was not able to find file ***hello.txt*** which in real was getting passed as ***hello.txt.txt***

Simple step on windows to view the extension:

1. Press window
2. Search "File Explorer Options"
3. In view tab, uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types".

Comment: Bring that file at some other location. Are you trying it from onedrive?

Comment: even though i have changed the location but still getting error

Comment: Write code: if os.path.exists(path_of_file): print ('file found') else ('not found') Check in which condition it is falling!

Comment: it returns me result not found

Comment: Which means the file not exists!

Comment: file is actually there on that location :(

Comment: 1. Press window 2. Search "File Explorer Options" 3. In view tab, uncheck "Hide extensions for known file types". Now, check you original file name and let me know what is the name? Is it hello.txt or hello.txt.txt ?

Comment: i have renamed the file and it is hi.txt.txt

Comment: I hope now you got the solution. This was the reason why it was not able to recognize your file. Hope it will solve this

Comment: The double backslashes are wrong (but harmless). Inside a raw string, backslashes do not need escaping. It just so happens that Windows apparently ignores the second one in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using forward slash instead of backslash?
Please try changing the directory string to:

```
"C:/Users/Kazmi-PC/OneDrive/Desktop/hello.txt"
```

It seems like this issue is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567785/error-with-double-backslash-in-windows-path-in-python)