# I am trying to create a todo list in python

Tags: python, file, path

the code should take what i worte in the input and add it to the txt file but i get an error because of the path please take a look.

```
main = input("What Task Would You Like To Add?       >   ")

f = open("C:\tdl\tdlp\MyToDoList.txt", "w")
f.write("content added")
f.close()

f = open("MyToDoList.txt", "r")
print(f.read())
```

I have tried replacing file formats and paths

Comment: ignore the <code> part

Comment: why not just remove it instead of making a comment to ignore it? Would be easier, and clearer too

Comment: please include the error message. It appears you are not escaping your baskslashes, and arenot opening the file in "append" mode `a`, but overwrite instead

Comment: you're writing "content added" to the file but you want to write `main`

Comment: Please give a minimal reproducible example. It's easier to understand how to help.

Comment: The error message is :   OSError:  [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'C:\tdl\tdlp\MyToDoList.txt'

Comment: There are multiple reasons why this code may raise error. 1. You didn't close the file handler. Use with statement. 2. Your path may be wrong 3. \\ vs \ vs /

Comment: Use / instead of backslashes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567785/error-with-double-backslash-in-windows-path-in-python