# Issue with slashes (\) in listdir

Tags: python, directory

I have been having issues when trying to insert information to listdir.

initially, I have tried to manually put in the info:

`for file in os.listdir(r'H:\My Documents')`

where I get this error: `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\My Documents'`

then the below

```
list_of_directory = r'H:\My Documents' 
for file in os.listdir(list_of_directory):
```

to which I got the same error.

I have tried everything including the solution mentioned here [Error with double backslash in Windows path in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22567785/error-with-double-backslash-in-windows-path-in-python)
but it wouldn't work.

can you please help? The rest of the code is ready and it's so frustrating that it has to wait due to this glitch!

Comment: Are you very sure there *is* a folder called `H:\My Documents`? What happens if you do `dir "H:\My Documents"` at a console prompt?

Comment: Yes, there definitely is. I'm not sure I'm getting what you're saying about dir, as I'm new to Python. Should I replace any part of the code?

Comment: I was asking you to type `dir "H:\My Documents"` at a _Windows console prompt_. Nothing to do with Python. I know you believe definitely that the folder does exist. But in my experience, a Windows folder called `My Documents` is typically a subsubfolder of `Users` and so is *not* at the root directory level. So I was asking you to cut and paste a command into a Windows console session that you had not typed yourself that would confirm or disconfirm your conviction with a couple of keystrokes. Retyping it could reintroduce a previous error. I do this myself when I hit this sort of problem.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. Tbh I looked into it a bit further. The Documents folder was just an example. I was looking to incorporate a samba link into the code but I see there are multiple issues with this type of links due to their own nature.

Answer (score 1):

You should just be able to use a forwards slash instead on any OS, because the os library replaces forwards slahes with baclwards slashes for Windows. If that doesn't work, you could try using the `pathlib` library.

```py
from pathlib import Path
data_folder = Path("source_data/text_files/")
file_to_open = data_folder / "raw_data.txt"
```

If you wanted, you could even use `pathlib` to convert a Unix to a Windows path.

```py
from pathlib import Path, PureWindowsPath
filename = Path("source_data/text_files/raw_data.txt")
path_on_windows = PureWindowsPath(filename)
```

So your code would become:

```py
from pathlib import Path
list_of_directory = Path('H:/My Documents').resolve()
for file in os.listdir(list_of_directory):
  print(file)
```

Comment: I'm still getting an error that this directory doesn't exist

Comment: Try the other solution I've added.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to catch the file not found error:

```py
list_of_directory = r'H:\My Documents'
try:
    for file in os.listdir(list_of_directory):
        ...
except FileNotFoundError:
    print(list_of_directory, "not found")
```

This will allow the program to continue and do something else when the folder does not exist.

Comment: I need the folder to exist, as I will need to access it to retrieve some files

Comment: Well, this code will tell you that the folder doesn't exist, so you will know that there are no files to retrieve.